If $f$ is injective, what do we know about $f'$?
If $f: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is injective and differentiable, where $(a,b)$ is an open interval, then what properties we can deduce about the zeros of $f'$?
We can not get that $f' \neq 0$. One example is $f(t) = t^3$ and $f'(0)=0$. I think at least we know that $f'$ can not equal $0$ on any subinterval of $(a,b)$. Otherwise, using Rolle's theorem, we can deduce a contradiction.
So, is there some other advanced properties about the zeros of $f'$. For example, I guess would the zeros of $f'$ be isolated?

you can clearly say that the roots of $f'$ have even multiplicity

@AkshatMishra What is your definition of multiplicity if it's not an integer?

@INS-ANAI Please edit your post to specify first what kind of function $f$ is. I guess it is a differentiable function (or $C^1$? or $C^\infty$?) from $(a,b)$ to $\Bbb R$ (or to $\dots$?).

Are you even sure $f'$ exists everywhere in $]a,b[$?

Even if $f$ is required to be differentiable, you can get some really weird sets of zeroes for $f'$. For example, $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x) + x$ is injective on $\mathbb R$ and has infinitely many zeroes in $[-1,1]$.

A nice example of a family of injective arbitrarily-differentiable functions whose derivatives have a non-isolated zero is $f(x) = (x^{-1} + \sin(x^{-1}))^{-n}$ for $n$ an odd number. You can find even weirder $C^\infty$ examples using this fact.

@IzaakvanDongen Very nice comment, thank you!
